# How to simultaneously display a splash screen and then my JFrame?

Tags: java, sleep, splash-screen, thread-sleep

I am working on a splash screen.  I managed to make a class. Below is a class that displays a splash screen. My problem is If I call this class from a JFrame and run, both JFrame and Splash screen runs at the same time and after the duration the splash screen is supposed to last Both of them is closed. How to I make them display simultaneously ?

Thanks a bunch

```
public class Splash extends JWindow {

AbsoluteLayout abs;
AbsoluteConstraints absImage, absBar;
ImageIcon image;
JLabel label;
JProgressBar bar;

public Splash() {
    abs = new AbsoluteLayout();
    absImage = new AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0);
    absBar = new AbsoluteConstraints(0, 210);
    label = new JLabel();
    image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("anime.gif"));
    label.setIcon(image);
    bar = new JProgressBar();
    bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,10));
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(abs);
    this.getContentPane().add(label, absImage);
    this.getContentPane().add(bar, absBar);

    new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                bar.setValue(i);
                try {
                    sleep(80);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Splash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }.start();
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What effect do you think that

```
System.exit(0);
```

will have on your program? This is a sledgehammer way to close a window since it will cause the JVM to exit, closing any and all things that it was running.

Have you looked at using the SplashScreen object that Java Swing provides?

Comment: I know what that line of code does. I just didnot found an alternative that is why I am here asking help. Thank I will check out SplashScreen in swing

Comment: @da_elysian_fields: If you want a window to not be displayed, you can call `setVisible(false)` on the window. But again `System.ext(0)` will end the program with no chance for recovery.

Comment: *"SplashScreen object that Java Swing provides"*  (polite cough) ITYM *"..AWT provides"* & it is the best way to approach this.

Comment: that is little helpful but how am I going to open my JFrame only after the splash screen is off.

Comment: @Andrew: but of course -- I meant AWT. How silly of you to mis-read the above to imply "Swing".

Comment: @da_elysian_fields *"going to open my JFrame only after the splash screen is off. "* Yes, but the `SplashScreen` class provides a method to get the splash URL, that can then be used in your later splash.  See also [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for more details.  I think @Hov has already addressed the main problem in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.dipose();
```

The dipose() will close the window.