# how to set Jframe for 5 second

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using `netbeans 7.1.1,` to create a JFrame. I want to automatically dispose the `JFrame` 5 seconds after calling `setVisible()` . How can I do this?

Comment: Thread.sleep(5000); but it will wait for  5 second before show the JFrame.

Comment: i think you are looking for splash screen..

Comment: Or a [dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513).

Comment: @Unni Kris :same as this

Comment: this may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668308/how-to-simultaneously-display-a-splash-screen-and-then-my-jframe and http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/splashScreen.html

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226164/how-to-move-jlabel-every-second/13226370#13226370) for nice example of Swing Timer. you would need to call `setRepeats(false);` on timer instance.

Answer (score 3):

HINT

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to wait for 5 seconds before calling `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` whichever way you want it implemented. Hidden/Disposed

Answer (score 1):

Did u do your research on this? Seems straight forward.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
          // this should be final
          jframe.dispose();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please Promote research !! avoid giving cooked up code samples.

Comment: Seems straightforward but with this approach you violate the Swing threading rules. Either wrap that `dispose` call in an `SwingUtilities.invokexxx` call or use a `javax.swing.Timer`