# How to make a JFrame close itself after 10 seconds?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a JFrame that closes after 10 seconds after openning.

I know that you can use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` , but you need to manually click to close the frame.

If you could help me with some codelines.

Thanks!

Comment: This post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231185/how-to-set-jframe-for-5-second

Comment: Thanks man it s perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javax.swing.Timer like this:

```
new Timer(10_000, (e) -> { frame.setVisible(false); frame.dispose(); }).start();
```

The advantage of using the javax.swing.Timer option is that it doesn't violate Swing threading rules.

As the Javadocs say:

> The javax.swing.Timer has two features that can make it a little
> easier to use with GUIs. First, its event handling metaphor is
> familiar to GUI programmers and can make dealing with the
> event-dispatching thread a bit simpler. Second, its automatic thread
> sharing means that you don't have to take special steps to avoid
> spawning too many threads. Instead, your timer uses the same thread
> used to make cursors blink, tool tips appear, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        jFrame.dispose();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```